# Conditionally stop bash loop and send /stop command to game server

Tags: shell-script, minecraft

I'm using a loop to automatically restart a minecraft server if it crashes or stops. This is great for crashes or scheduled reboots, however there are times we specifically want to stop the server and not reboot.

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
java ... args
sleep 5
done
```

Ideally, I could somehow tell this loop to end *and* pass in a `/stop` command to the minecraft server, so that I don't need to do both.

I'm very new to shell scripting so I'm not sure on the right approach.

Ubuntu 18.xx if that matters.

Comment: Sounds like a daemon/service would be better suited for this task than a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Panki's comment, it sounds like you're better off running your minecraft server as a service.

You will basically have to add a few files to the 'systemd' directory which enable the OS to keep the process running if you tell it to start and stop it when you tell it to stop.

There are a bunch of tutorials that can help you set this up. 
For example:

Detailed: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-systemd-service-unit-in-linux

Easy to follow: https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6

Minecraft specific: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-minecraft-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/#creating-systemd-unit-file

For keeping it 'started', you should add the following line to your service:

```
Restart=always
```

See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/611525/standard-or-best-way-to-keep-alive-process-started-by-init-d

Comment: Is this the same as the systemd approach described here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-minecraft-server-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: If not, would this approach allow me to access the console, or would I need the rcon setup to send commands?

Comment: @helion3 Yes, that is exactly it under the "Creating Systemd Unit File" :)